# How to understand verses 52:21 and 74:38-39?

Tags: quran

In 52:21 we are talking about believers and about Paradise and it is said that everyone is a hostage of what he did. That is, believers will receive Paradise for what they did.

> And those who believed and whose descendants followed them in faith -
> We will join with them their descendants, and We will not deprive them
> of anything of their deeds. Every person, for what he earned, is
> retained. (52:21)

But at 74:38-39, the hostage position does not apply to believers.

> Every soul, for what it has earned, will be retained  Except the
> companions of the right(74:38-39)

How to coordinate this?

I have read many tafsirs, but I have not found an answer in any of them. I really need an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Surah At-Tur ayat 21:

(As for those who believe and whose descendants follow them in faith, We will elevate their descendants to their rank, never discounting anything ˹of the reward˺ of their deeds)
Here, Allah talks about how the descendants of the pious believers who will try their best to imitate their parents will be given the same ranks as the pious believers even though their deeds are not as good as their parents and their deeds will not be decreased.

(Every person will reap only what they sowed)
But their mistakes will not be shared. Allah will not punish anyone for the sins of others. No matter if it is from their decedents or their ancestors.

Surah Al-Muddaththir ayat 38-39:

(Every soul will be detained for what it has done)
Meaning everyone will be detained in hell for their sins.

(Except those on the Right)
Except for the people who were given the Book of Deeds in their right hands.

Interpretation taken from Tafsir Ibn Kathir and Maarif-Ul-Qur'an

The two are talking about different things.

I hope this helped. Allah knows the best.

Comment: I have read both tafsir, and I am not happy with these interpretations. After all, it is clearly stated there in both verses that a person is a pledge of what he has acquired. But at 74:39, an exception already follows.

Comment: Because in context, both of the ayats are talking about different things, even though the phrasing is similar.